# "Failed password" and "Invalid user" - Secure Shell Server

Tags: ubuntu, openssh, sshd

I installed ssh-server on Ubuntu 18.04.01.

When I try to access the server with PuTTY the error "access denied" is shown.
The server log says "failed password" and "invalid user".

I also changed "PermitRootLogin yes" in sshd_config.
But it still doesn't work.
I am trying to figure out the problem since hours.

Does somebody know, what configuration has to he changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have access to the server's terminal, use the command "cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd" to see all users.

Comment: I'm sitting in front of the server and the credentials I used are correct.

Comment: Are you entering the exact capitalization of root?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I even tried login with a standard account. This doesn't work either.

Comment: I mean by using the creds exactly as they are set, (cant use "Root" for "root")
if you still have access, you could just make a different user with sudo

Comment: Yes, I am using the exact credits. But still doesn't work.

Comment: I had to write everithing in lower case.

Comment: *I had to write everithing in lower case* means you weren't doing it the first time therefore it couldn't work because it's case sensitive. It would be nice *not* to have to answer such trivialities here.

Answer (score 0):

You must restart sshd after updating the config file.

Comment: I did restart the server.

Comment: indeed, and after a `systemctl reload-or-restart sshd` it did NOT work for me, only after `systemctl restart sshd`  so be warned....